# Having probs with hibernate when creating a table , it was working fine before but then experiencing some probs

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to `hibernate` and I'm experiencing some minor problems to which I have also posted the code, hoping for some suggestions from all the experienced people out there. I have also posted the error which I'm getting.

This is my model class

```
package com.hibernate.arjun;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Car_Info {

    @Column(name = "CarName")
    private String car_name;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CarNo")
    private String car_no;
    @Column(name = "CarModel")
    private String car_model;

    public String getCar_name() {
        return car_name;
    }

    public void setCar_name(String car_name) {
        this.car_name = car_name;
    }

    public String getCar_no() {
        return car_no;
    }

    public void setCar_no(String car_no) {
        this.car_no = car_no;
    }

    public String getCar_model() {
        return car_model;
    }

    public void setCar_model(String car_model) {
        this.car_model = car_model;
    }
}
```

This is my main class

```
package com.hibernate.arjun;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class MainCar {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Car_Info car_Info = new Car_Info();
        car_Info.setCar_name("Ferrari");
        car_Info.setCar_model("Italian");


        SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(car_Info);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

and this is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CarTable</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>


    <mapping class="com.hibernate.arjun.Car_Info" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I m just creating a table from hibernate which three columns but then this is the error I'm experiencing

```
Sep 23, 2014 5:02:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists Car_Info
Hibernate: create table Car_Info (CarNo varchar(255) not null auto_increment, CarModel varchar(255), CarName varchar(255), primary key (CarNo))
Sep 23, 2014 5:02:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table Car_Info (CarNo varchar(255) not null auto_increment, CarModel varchar(255), CarName varchar(255), primary key (CarNo))
Sep 23, 2014 5:02:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Incorrect column specifier for column 'CarNo'
Sep 23, 2014 5:02:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: insert into Car_Info (CarModel, CarName) values (?, ?)
Sep 23, 2014 5:02:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Sep 23, 2014 5:02:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'cartable.car_info' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.hibernate.arjun.MainCar.main(MainCar.java:19)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'cartable.car_info' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 22 more
```

I have also one more doubt. Is it necessary to create a table before in MySql, because when I use create in the `cfg.xml` file it gives me error, it automatically deletes the table, what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> set it to update and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says

```
Incorrect column specifier for column 'CarNo'
```

because you have declared the field as `String` instead of `int`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "CarNo")
private String car_no;
```

As you said `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` hibernate assumed that the field car_no as a number and tried to create your table as:

```
CarNo varchar(255) not null auto_increment
```

Here you can clearly see that hibernate is trying to include auto_increment which is not correct for `String` data type. So the table creation itself failed with error :

```
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table Car_Info (CarNo varchar(255) not null auto_increment, CarModel varchar(255), CarName varchar(255), primary key (CarNo))
```

To fix the issue change your field to any data type like `int` or `long` etc where the `auto_increment` is applicable.

If you still want to use `car_no` as `String` then you need to use the `GenerationType.ASSIGNED` generation strategy which is the default strategy for any identifiers so just removing the generation strategy means you need to assign the identifier manually in your code before calling `session.save(Object)` method.

```
@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.ASSIGNED) -- this line is optional
@Column(name = "CarNo")
private String car_no;
```

Regarding the property **hbm2ddl.auto**, when you set its value to [create](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#create%28boolean,%20boolean%29) then hibernate automatically runs the `drop` commands and then creates the tables while creating SessionFactory. You have to set its value to `update` if you don't want to drop the tables every time when you run the application.

Refer to this link for more details on hbm2ddl - [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'cartable.car_info' doesn't exist

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee, please check the logs from beginning then you will understand why the error ` Table cartable.car_info doesn't exist` came. Also go through my answer to understand why the table creation failed.

Comment: Thanx alot for taking out ur time to explain me the mistakes and about the update it did work , thanx

Answer (score 0):

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` cannot be used to generate `string` id.
If you want use `string` Id then just put `@Id` over `private String car_no;` like,

```
   @Id
    @Column(name = "CarNo")
    private String car_no;
```

otherwise  change the datatype of `car_no` to `int`.

Comment: Thanx alot for replying and yea my bad , i understood my mistake will keep this is in my mind